# Fade in and out doesn't work with React child element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have an App that shows an icon. When clicking on the icon a sibling element should fade in. Subsequently, when clicked again the same sibling element should fade out. I have tried with and without `CSSTransition`, but this just doesn't work. I think it might have to do with the conditional rendering of the sibling.

```
const TitlesSettings = () => {
  const [showInput, setShowInput] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setShowInput(!showInput);
  };

  return (
    <section className="settings">
        <div className="settings-button">
            <i
                className="fas fa-bars"
                onClick={handleClick}
                onKeyDown={handleClick}
                role="button"
            />
        </div>
        <CreateTitle buttonText="Submit" renderElement={showInput} />
    </section>
  );
};
```

I am passing the showInput state prop to the child to conditionally render it's appearance. Here is the `CreateTitle` element, please bare with the disorder since it's also a graphql component:

```
const Input = props => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const { buttonText, renderElement } = props;

    const onTitleChange = event => {
        const { value } = event.target;
        setTitle(value);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const settingsBox = document.createElement('.settingsBox');
        renderElement
            ? settingsBox.classList.toggle('active')
            : settingsBox.classList.toggle('inactive');
    }, [renderElement]);

    return (
        <Mutation
            mutation={CREATE_TITLE_MUTATION}
            variables={{ title }}
            refetchQueries={[{ query: ALL_TITLES_QUERY }]}
        >
            {(createTitle, { loading, error }) => {
                return (
                    <InputWrapper classNames="settingsBox">
                        {renderElement ? (
                            <form
                                onSubmit={async e => {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    await createTitle();
                                }}
                                className="input-form"
                            >
                                <label htmlFor="createArticle">
                                    <input
                                        type="text"
                                        placeholder="Enter title of new article"
                                        id="createArticle"
                                        onChange={onTitleChange}
                                        value={title}
                                        name="title"
                                        disabled={loading}
                                        aria-busy={loading}
                                    />
                                </label>
                                <input type="submit" value={buttonText} />
                            </form>
                        ) : null}
                    </InputWrapper>
                );
            }}
        </Mutation>
    );
};
```

The `InputWrapper` currently is controlled by `styled-components`:

```
const InputWrapper = styled.div`
    transition: all 1.8s ease;
    opacity: 0;

    form {...}
```

Also, when the condition to render the element is not fulfilled, the element is removed from the DOM. I have been unable to attach a class or transition to it.

Please help me achieve the rather simple task of fading in and out a sibling element.

Comment: `const settingsBox = document.createElement('.settingsBox');` looks like a good place to start - a `.settingsBox` is not an element

Comment: 'simple task' isn't simple in react, the way it works (virtual dom) - search/google for `animation react`